# Rails - email as part of a conversation (mailboxer?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that needs 'conversations' between two entities around a shared object (a proposal). Very simple, just two or more users chatting about the shared object. I have looked at a couple of gems, including Mailboxer, but was thinking of handrolling it instead.

However, the client wants the users to A) be sent email of the conversation (no problem) and B) be able to reply to those emails, where the reply gets added to the conversation. This would likely be similar to how eg airbnb handles it:
[image: airbnb_temp_email]

It's the B part that I'm struggling with. To my knowledge, Mailboxer wouldn't handle this. Are there other gems that do? Or do I need an entirely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should use gem msgthr to handle conversational mail.
https://rubygems.org/gems/msgthr/versions/1.2.0